# MongoDB java driver: get all unique value of a field restricted by another field

Tags: java, mongodb

Using the MongoDB java driver I would like to get all unique values of a field called "category" where the field called "companyKey" has the value "XYZ".

First question, is this possible?

Second question, do you have any idea what the syntax would look like? I can't find any relevant docs ... pointers to docs would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
DBCollection collection=...;
collection.distinct(key, query);
```

[API docs.](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#distinct%28java.lang.String,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29)

Example:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("companyKey", "XYZ");
collection.distinct("category", query);
```